# Terminal/System Application way to list/detect webcam

Tags: virtualbox, webcam

How can I check if I have a webcam using either terminal or an existing application in Ubuntu?

I am running Ubuntu through Virtual Box. My host has a webcam but Ubuntu cannot access/find it. So I want to be able to check whats exactly wrong.

Also is the webcam in Ubuntu/linux typically `dev/0`?

Info re Virtual Box:

- Bridged Adapter enabled
- USB 2.0 enabled
- The webcam has been added: QCM Microsoft LifeCam Front [2152]
- With my bluetooth I usually have to turn it on in the host before I can get Ubuntu to just recognise the Bluetooth adapter (then I can turn it on and use it). The same isn't working for the webcam.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ls -ltrh /dev/video*
```

to list all video devices picked up by the kernel. The first video device by default is /dev/video0.